# dbpedia html in result

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Sometimes I recognize some html fragments in property dbpedia-owl:abstract

Here is an example http://dbpedia.org/page/Albizia_julibrissin where you do see some html fragments (***emphasized***) in english abstract:

This page is about the tree described by Antonio Durazzini. John Gilbert Baker used the same scientific name to refer to Prain's Albizia kalkora, the Mimosa kalkora of William Roxburgh. ***colspan=2 style="text-align: center; background-color: transparent; text-align:center; border: 1px solid red;" | Persian Silk Tree File:Albizzia julibrissin in Sevastopol 1. jpg Habitus Conservation status Not evaluated colspan=2 style="text-align: center; background-color: transparent; text-align:center; border: 1px solid red;" | Scientific classification Kingdom: Plantae (unranked): Angiosperms (unranked): Eudicots (unranked): Rosids Order: Fabales Family: Fabaceae Genus: Albizia Species: A. julibrissin colspan=2 style="text-align: center; background-color: transparent; text-align:center; border: 1px solid red;" | Binomial name Albizia julibrissin colspan=2 style="text-align: center; background-color: transparent; text-align:center; border: 1px solid red;" | Synonyms Many, see text*** Albizia julibrissin is a species of legume in the genus Albizia, native to southwestern and eastern Asia, from Persia east to China and Korea. It is also widely known as "Mimosa" and "'Persian silk tree'. The genus is named after the Italian nobleman Filippo degli Albizzi, belonging to the famous Florentine family Albizzi, who introduced it to Europe in the mid-18th century, and it is sometimes incorrectly spelled Albizzia. The specific epithet julibrissin is a corruption of the Persian word gul-i abrisham (گل ابریشم) which means "silk flower" (from gul گل "flower" + abrisham ابریشم "silk").

Is there any way to strip/extract these fragments so that the abstract property is human readable?

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem in the data entry dbpedia. The header

> "This page is about the tree Described by Antonio Durazzini. John
>   Gilbert Baker used the same scientific name to Refer to Prain's
>   Albizia Kakora, the Mimosa Kakora of William Roxburgh."

is not usually associated with the property dbpedia-owl : abstract.

From the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), a SPARQL 1.1 solution is :

```
select distinct ?clean_abstract 
where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albizia_julibrissin> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract.
  filter (lang(?abstract) = 'en')
  bind (strafter(?abstract,"see text ") as ?clean_abstract)
}
```

And another solution including this header (but it should not be linked to this property) :

```
select distinct ?clean_abstract 
where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albizia_julibrissin> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract.
  filter (lang(?abstract) = 'en')
  bind (concat(strbefore(?abstract,"colspan="), strafter(?abstract,"see text ")) as ?clean_abstract)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Your proposals will work for [http://dbpedia.org/page/Albizia_julibrissin](http://dbpedia.org/page/Albizia_julibrissin) but they won't fit in general. There are other examples, e.g. [http://dbpedia.org/page/Cinnamomum_camphora](http://dbpedia.org/page/Cinnamomum_camphora) where the header has to be stripped differently. Unfortunately I don't see a pattern which would work for all examples.